# Strange behavior with Observable results in Angular/Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I have the following problem. Imagine a single Angular 2 service:

```
validate() {
        return this.http.get('api/validate', data); }
```

When I am trying to consume the above API, everything is Okay with that:

```
this.ValidationService.validate().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('data returned from api', result);
        });
```

and the result is an object:

```
{status: "success", data: {…}}
```

However, what will drive me crazy is when I am trying:

```
this.ValidationService.validate().subscribe(result => {
                console.log('data returned from api', result.data);
            });
```

Typescript complains there is no **data** property and there is a compilation error!! At the same time from the following I am getting `true`...

```
this.ValidationService.validate().subscribe(result => {
            console.log('data returned from api', result.hasOwnProperty('data'));
        });
```

I also tried `result['data']`. It did not work as well. Any idea about what may happen?

Comment: you are in angular5?

Comment: are you using httpClient?

Comment: What's the compile error?

Comment: `result['data']` rather than `result.data`

Comment: I think you should add type for your resylt to subscribe method. (result: any)

Comment: I am in Angular 4.4.6 and I am using HttpClient

Comment: you have to provide a type for your HttpClient response; thus it will know the shape of your data when parsing

Answer (score 1):

I think you miss .json() to get the body of the response:

```
this.ValidationService.validate().subscribe(result => {
  console.log('data returned from api', result.json());
});
```

If it's that I think it's better to move .json() to your service to don't have many .json() everywhere in your code:

```
validate() {
  return this.http.get('api/validate', data).map(res => res.json()); 
}
```

Comment: See my comment for @Andersson

Comment: @Unknowndeveloper Can you the full code of your service file in thequestion?

Answer (score 0):

try this, add ?  to prevent errors  :

```
console.log('data returned from api', result?.data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an any type for the result like below:

```
this.ValidationService.validate().subscribe((result:any) => {
```

You may want to add proper typings for your responses as well, this will make your code more readable and maintainable